# Graphql date range as input field

Tags: date, graphql, standards, apollo-server, date-range

I am implementing a GraphQL API for a automobile inventory which stores the info like registration, inDate, outDate, etc.

I need to implement a fetch API to retrieve the info of all cars which came in/ went out

1. on a certain date
2. or in a certain date range like a week or month

Assuming the current looks like

```
scalar Date

input QueryArguments {
  registration: string
  inDate: unkownType
  outDate: unkownType
}

type Query {
  automobiles(input: QueryArguments!): [Automobile]
}

type Automobile{
  registration: string
  inDate: Date
  outDate: Date
}
```

What would be the standard/accepted way for GraphQL input field to support both a single Date and a Date Range.

I came across a stackoverlow article in which it was suggested to use a custom type

```
type DateRangeInput {
  start: Date
  end: Date
}
```

It works fine for Date range, but if a single date needs to be provided we should send it in either `start` or end `field` or introduce a different field apart from those, but it doesnt look clean in the single date scenario.

UPDATE:
Based on `Michel Floyd` suggestion, I am going with the approach of custom input type.

```
input DateInput{
    onDates: [Date],
    inRange: DateRangeInput
}
input DateRangeInput {
  start: Date!
  end: Date!
}
```

Where it supports selection of multiple individual dates, or a date range. Any restrictions should be implemented in resolver.

This approach doesn't look clean, but this option suits my requirement best with current apollo-graphql capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

All your fields in your input type are currently optional. You can add to that:

```
scalar Date

input QueryArguments {
  registration: string
  inDate: Date
  outDate: Date
  start: Date
  end: Date  
}

type Query {
  automobiles(input: QueryArguments!): [Automobile]
}
```

Then you can query with any combination of arguments:

```
query myQuery($input: QueryArguments!) {
  Query(input: $input) {
    … automobile fields
  }
}
```

`QueryArguments` could then be:

```
{ start: '2024-01-01', end: '2024-01-31'}
```

or:

```
{ inDate: '2024-01-09' }
```

Or any combination. Your resolver code would be responsible for ensuring that if `start` is provided then `end` also has to be there (if that's what you want).

OR, you can have two input types, each of which is optional.

```
input QueryArguments {
  registration: string
  inDate: Date
  outDate: Date
}

input DateRange {
  start: Date
  end: Date
}
```

and then define your query as:

```
type Query {
  automobiles(input: QueryArguments, range: DateRange): [Automobile]
}
```

Note the lack of an exclamation point after either of those types, that means both are optional but your resolver can enforce that at least one has to be there.

Comment: The date range should be applicable for both inDate and outDate i.e., both inDate and outDate should support both scenarios where a single date can be passed or both can be passed.

Comment: You can't really have an input variable that is either a scalar or a tuple. You could have it be an array with either 1 or 2 elements.

Comment: I was also thinking of using an array with max length 2, but from my understanding graphql doesnt support size restriction for list inputs natively. It would be tricky for me to validte the length from resolvers as there can be multiple fields like this.

Comment: You're correct that GraphQL doesn't support size limits on list inputs in the syntax.